# Difference with this.Property and Property in C# .NET

Tags: c#, android, properties, mono, this

We've been struggling to debug something quite strange, and I'd like some insight on why/what happened. Let me give you some context of course.

A simple method makes an async call with its `ViewModel`, using one of the `ViewModel's` properties inside it.

On one side of the call, our property (called Itinerary, for the sake of the example) is there, in perfect condition. On the other side of the method, inside the async call, for some reason, it's `null`.

The stack trace shows Itinerary going null in between, where only System.Runtime methods are called and could not possibly influence the itinerary itself.

We spent about 3 hours going around this stack trace and the code variables, going from non null to null.

The Itinerary property was not null even though it's getter is `return _itinerary` which was null at all times in the stacktrace ! It literally makes no sense.

Everywhere in the code Itinerary shows null, except when you hover the property declaration itself. Which also makes no sense, right?

At some point we just typed `this.Itinerary` because, well, we didn't know what to do and it was desperate.

And it worked.

The property is now kept sane during the whole async process and everything runs smoothly just like it used it.

Notes :

We're working with the Mono framework, in Xamarin, using Xamarin Studio and this happened in the android runs only. iOS has a clean Itinerary.

Here is some pseudo code :

```
//In a previous method
viewModel.DoSomethingAsync();   //Here the itinerary is valid
```

Just 3 lines under

```
 async void DoSomethingAsync(){

      DoSomethingElseWith(Itinerary);  //Here Itinerary is null, adding this.  fixes the issue.

  }
```

I only have one Itinerary property, there are no name conflict.

**Now my question is :**

Can anyone, anywhere, think of some kind of explanation that could happen, ever, where `this.Property` is different than `Property`, while working in the same class.

Comment: Why did you remove the android tag?

Comment: The only reason I see for using `this.` would make a difference is that there is another local variable with the same name. Can you show any code?

Comment: sorry i thought question is not relevant to android. added android tag again.

Comment: I added some pseudo code and the real code is pretty much the same

Comment: Does the *IL* change when you compile this.Property vs. Property?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this code:

```
   public class YourClass
    {
        public int id;
        public YourClass(int id)
        {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
```

you can use parameter with the same Name as an attribute, because in the constructor it's obvious, that you mean the attribute, if you write "this.id". If you only write "id = id;" your program would do an useless assignment and the id-attribute would still be null.

Comment: Indeed you are right, but this is not the case in my situation. :(

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some specific problem with Mono/Android. Here's something you could try:

Can you try modifying the method `DoSomethingElseWith` so that it doesn't take an argument of the type of the property, but pass the actual current object instead? Something along those lines:

```
// Interface for DI reasons. :)
interface IItineraryContainer { string Itinerary { get; } }

class MyObj : IItineraryContainer
{
    public string Itinerary { get; set; }

    public async void DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        ItineraryOperations.DoSomethingElseWith(this);
    }
}

class ItineraryOperations
{
    public static void DoSomethingElseWith(IItineraryContainer container)
    {
        string valueToWorkWith = container.Itinerary;
    }
}
```

This might not be the code you're looking for, but it might help isolating the problem further.